# simple program wont compile

Tags: c++

Please take a look at my code. The error I get in Visual Studio is

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Employee::getId(void)" (?getId@Employee@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
```

Employee.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEES
#define EMPLOYEES

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string name;
    int id;
public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string nm, int idd);
    string getName();
    int getId();
};

#endif
```

Employee.cpp

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <string>

Employee::Employee()
{
    name="unknown";
    id=0;
}

Employee::Employee(string nm, int idd)
{
    name=nm;
    id=idd;
}

string Employee::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Employee::getId()
{
    return id;
}
```

driver

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    Employee bob("bob", 3);
    cout << bob.getId();
}
```

Comment: You'd better not use "using namespace std;" in headers (not related to your question).

Comment: what about the compile and linking line ?

Comment: how do you compile your program ?

Comment: @Stefano, sorry i dont understand your question. I'm a student coder

Comment: @Muggen, I press f5 in visual studio

Comment: I'm not using Visual but it works with me. There is no linking problem with calling the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to link the two files together. Make sure that you're linking Employee.cpp and  main.cpp files together. Are they added to the same VS project?

**EDIT**: check out [this link](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~resource/supporting/vc/vc_build/vc_build.html#build2). It's outdated, but looks like you did **not** make a project that contains all the files. They should be linked automagically.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not linking Employee.o, result of Employee.cpp, or directly adding Employee.cpp to compile with main.cpp

The final linker sees the main but can't find the things defined in Employee.cpp